# Laravel - How to include API Subscription key in my Laravel End Point

Tags: laravel, api

In my Laravel-5.8, I am trying to consume API end point GET Request with Guzzle:

```
  use App\Employee;
  use App\Department;

  public function index() 
  {  
      $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
       $res = $client->request('GET','https://api.employees.net/allemployees')->getBody();

        $clientdatas = json_decode($res, true);

     ...
  }
```

The API has subscription key.

In POSTMAN, I did it this way and it works:

```
GET        https://api.employees.net/allemployees?key=fgfdhsddddDDDDD
```

How do I add the subscription key to my Laravel api

```
  public function index() 
  {  
      $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
       $res = $client->request('GET','https://api.employees.net/allemployees')->getBody();

        $clientdatas = json_decode($res, true);

     ...
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't do same URL request from Postman and from within method that is called from postman. Check again logic what should be the task. Also, try `request()->get('key')` for grabbing value from Postman request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking is how to [send query string parameters in Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters). You can add your API key to your request by using the following:

```
public function index() 
  {  
      $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
       $res = $client->request('GET','https://api.employees.net/allemployees?key=fgfdhsddddDDDDD')->getBody();

        $clientdatas = json_decode($res, true);

     ...
  }
```

OR

```
public function index() 
  {  
      $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
       $res = $client->request('GET','https://api.employees.net/allemployees', [
           'query' => ['key' => 'fgfdhsddddDDDDD']
       ])->getBody();

        $clientdatas = json_decode($res, true);

     ...
  }
```